# Can I render markup in frontmatter fields in nuxt content?

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify-cms

I'm using Netlify CMS with Nuxt content. It seems that Netlify CMS will only allow edits to the frontmatter fields and not to the body of the markdown file. Even though I can set the frontmatter field type to markdown in the netlify CMS config file, I can't find a way in the template to parse this string as rendered html.

Using `<span v-html="page.content"></span>` doesn't work for this

And while `<nuxt-content :document="page" />` does render the content correctly it only shows the markdown body, not any of the frontmatter fields

I've actually tried Forestry which lets you edit the markdown body which works perfectly, but I'd like to find a way to use Netlify CMS for this